# railsのdb:seedをマルチスレッドで実行しようとするとActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutErrorが発生する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql, rails-activerecord

seed_fuを使ったseed投入をマルチスレッドで実行しようとして以下のようなコードを書きました。

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

SEED_PATH = "db/seeds/production"

# 同時に動くthreadの数をconnection_poolの数に制限する
LOCKS = Queue.new
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.size.times { LOCKS.push :lock }

def seed_thread(seed_file_name, *depend_thraeds)
  Thread.new do
    depend_thraeds.each(&:join)
    lock = LOCKS.pop
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection { SeedFu.seed(SEED_PATH, seed_file_name) }
    LOCKS.push lock
  end
end

{}.tap do |t|
  t[:region]     = seed_thread %r{/region.rb}
  t[:prefecture] = seed_thread %r{/prefecture.rb}, t[:region]
  t[:aaa]        = seed_thread %r{/aaa.rb}
  t[:bbb]        = seed_thread %r{/bbb.rb}
  t[:ccc]        = seed_thread %r{/ccc.rb}, t[:aaa], t[:bbb]
  t[:ddd]        = seed_thread %r{/ddd.rb}, t[:aaa], t[:ccc]
  t[:eee]        = seed_thread %r{/eee.rb}
  # 実際にはもっとテーブル数は多い
end.values.each(&:join)
```

これを実行すると `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` が発生することがあります。
発生確率はActiveRecord::Base.connection_poolの数を1にすると100%、5にすると体感で50%くらいです。

実行中のthreadの数 = connection_poolの数のときlockをかけて　`ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection {}` を実行させないつもりのコードなのですが、なぜ `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` が発生してしまうのでしょうか?

ご教授ください。

- ruby: 2.5.1
- rails: 5.2.0
- seed_fu: 2.3.9

---

以下のようにしました。

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

SEED_PATH = "db/seeds/production"
THREAD_NUM = 4

LOCKS = Queue.new
THREAD_NUM.times { LOCKS.push :lock }

def seed_thread(seed_file_name, *depend_thraeds)
  Thread.new do
    depend_thraeds.each(&:join)
    lock = LOCKS.pop
    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection { SeedFu.seed(SEED_PATH, seed_file_name) }
    rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError
      STDERR.puts "retry #{seed_file_name}"
      sleep 1
      retry
    end
    LOCKS.push lock
  end
end

{}.tap do |t|
  t[:region]     = seed_thread %r{/region.rb}
  t[:prefecture] = seed_thread %r{/prefecture.rb}, t[:region]
  t[:aaa]        = seed_thread %r{/aaa.rb}
  t[:bbb]        = seed_thread %r{/bbb.rb}
  t[:ccc]        = seed_thread %r{/ccc.rb}, t[:aaa], t[:bbb]
  t[:ddd]        = seed_thread %r{/ddd.rb}, t[:aaa], t[:ccc]
  t[:eee]        = seed_thread %r{/eee.rb}
  # 実際にはもっとテーブル数は多い
end.values.each(&:join)
```

Comment: モデルに、connection をハイジャックする系の gem とか入ってませんか？

Comment: connection をハイジャックする系のgemが入っている自覚はないですが、例えばどのようなgemがあるでしょうか?

Comment: たとえば、 octopus (https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus) とかは、 connection を独自でジャックしていたと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord の connection_pool 自体に、排他制御がかかっています。プログラム全体で見たときに、対象 DB への同時接続の排他制御に責任を持っているのは、なので、 connection_pool だと思います。

例えば、導入してた gem が何か勝手に connection を取得していた、とかはありうる話かな、と思っています。

だとすると、Thread を以下のように実行して、排他制御は connection_pool に任せる、というのはいかがでしょうか?

```
  Thread.new do
    depend_thraeds.each(&:join)
    loop do
      begin
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection { SeedFu.seed(SEED_PATH, seed_file_name) }
        break
      rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError
      end
    end
  end
```